# Free alternative of ViEmu?

Tags: visual-studio, viemu

Is there a free/open source alternative to ViEmu for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [VsVim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329). It is still in development, so it doesn't currently offer the same number of features as ViEmu, but it is free.